# Set page variable in BIRT report

Tags: java, gwt, birt

I have a BIRT report I'm calling with a report engine in GWT. I can set a report parameter with

```
task.setParameterValue("orderNumber", orderNum);
```

But how can I set a report variable value? I don't see anything in the API for setting one and I'm at a loss. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, a variable is internal in a report, otherwise it is a parameter. A workaround would be to initialize your report variable from a parameter: set the default value of the variable as "javascript expression" and just drag&drop a parameter. It will create an expression such

```
params["myParamVariable"].value
```

We can then use the report engine API to set the value of "myParamVariable"

Answer (score 0):

You must have to add same name parameter in report parameters in Data explorer in Birt engine then u can use `params["orderNum"].value`